# Calculating content of newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

In order to have a tikz picture adjust to some input values I have created something as the code below. In the code below the distance between A and C is twice as long as the distance between A and B as it should be. However, the number given ist not correct. Instead of 2*15 I would like to have 30.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\newcommand{\Anton}{15}
\newcommand{\Berta}{\Anton*2} 
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm,scale=1] 
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={<->}}   
    \tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white, font=\normalsize}} 
\node (A) at (0,0){A};
\node (B) at (\Anton,0){B};
\node (C) at (-\Berta,0){C};
% Maße Vertikal
\path (A) edge [mystyle] node {\Anton} (B);
\path (A) edge [mystyle] node {\Berta} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image: Results as is]

Is there a way to calculate the content of `\Berta`before using it as the lable on the `\path`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\pgfmathsetmacro` for a decimal number and `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` for an integer. Alternatively, if you want to handle both together, here's a variant of `\pgfmathsetmacro`. The way it works is as follows: our problem is that `\pgfmathsetmacro\test{1+1}` sets `\test` to `2.0`. So my variant checks whether the result is of the form `n.0` for some integer `n`, and if so drops the `0`. Other decimals are left alone.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\newcommand\mymathsetmacro[2]{\pgfmathparse{#2}\expandafter\mymathsetmacrohelper\pgfmathresult\nil\edef#1{\pgfmathresult}}
\def\mymathsetmacrohelper#1.#2#3\nil{\ifx0#2\ifx&#3& \def\pgfmathresult{#1}\fi \fi}
\newcommand{\Anton}{15}
\mymathsetmacro{\Berta}{\Anton*2}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm,scale=1]
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={<->}}
    \tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white, font=\normalsize}}
\node (A) at (0,0){A};
\node (B) at (\Anton,0){B};
\node (C) at (-\Berta,0){C};
% Maße Vertikal
\path (A) edge [mystyle] node {\Anton} (B);
\path (A) edge [mystyle] node {\Berta} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr From my Layman's point of view this solution (usinge `pgfmathtruncatemacro`instead of `newcommand`seems a lot simpler to create in the first place (and it is easyer to change my existing code to accomodate it). Could you try to explain the risks of this solution?

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to always use `\pgfmathsetmacro`instead of `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` in case I change one of the numbers to a decimal at some point? To answer this myself, the later may produce rather long number that do not look good at all. Could this be the reason why @cfr solution might be better?

Comment: The frustrating thing about `\pgfmathsetmacro` is that `\pgfmathsetmacro\test{1+1}` sets `\test` to `2.0`. If the values you are using are not always integers, then maybe it's better when they are integers to use `\pgfmathsetmacro\test{int(formula)}`.

Comment: See edit for a "best of both worlds" solution.

Comment: @HoodChatham `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`

Comment: @percusse I'm not sure what you mean. The point is to get a version so that `\mymathsetmacro\test{1+1}` sets `\test` to `2` and `\mymathsetmacro\test{3/2}` sets `\test` to `1.5`.

Answer (score 9):

I would do the whole thing with Ti*k*Z/PGF keys. If you want `\Anton` and `\Berta` available generally, you can use `\tikzset{}` in the preamble or at the beginning of the document.

There are various ways to do this. The way I've done it here involves setting up `\Anton` to store a simple value, defining an additional style (`double trouble`) to create `\Berta` from an argument using `\pgfmathsetmacro`, and then simply forwarding the value given to `Anton` to `double trouble` any time `Anton` is set.

This is more complicated to explain than to see in the code, I think!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\tikzset{%
  % key Anton stores a value in \Anton
  Anton/.store in=\Anton,
  % key double trouble sets \Berta to twice the argument it is given
  double trouble/.code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Berta{int(2*#1)}%
  },
  % any time the key Anton is used, the same value will be passed to double trouble
  Anton/.forward to=/tikz/double trouble,
  % make sure the key Anton is set to something so \Anton and \Berta have some default value
  Anton=15,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    x=1mm,
    y=1mm,
    mystyle/.style={<->},
    every node/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node (B) at (\Anton,0){B};
  \node (C) at (-\Berta,0){C};
  % Maße Vertikal
  % we can make this a bit more concise ...
  \path [mystyle] (A) edge node {\Anton} (B) edge node {\Berta} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Anton and Berta]

The advantage of using Ti*k*Z keys is that the user interface is intuitive and that it is easy to modify the values between or within `tikzpicture`s.

Adding the following after the above picture, for example, we change the value of both macros by setting `Anton=10` and then modify them again for just one `node`, setting `Anton=2`, so that `\Berta` produces `4` while `\Anton` still produces `10` when creating the nodes on the final line.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    x=1mm,
    y=1mm,
    mystyle/.style={draw=blue, thick, text=red},
    every node/.style={fill=white},
    Anton=10,
  ]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node (B) at (\Anton,0){B};
  \node (C) at (-\Berta,0){C};
  % Maße Verti
  % we can make this a bit more concise ...
  \path [mystyle] (A) edge node {\Anton} (B) edge node [Anton=2] {\Berta} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Anton and Berta]

Note that the distances used are all based on the initial value. The macros differ only when creating the node containing `\Berta`.

Whether this is useful and how useful depends, obviously, on the real use case. But it the kind of thing which is often required in Ti*k*Z pictures and it is nice to keep that flexibility, even if it is not of any immediate use.

## EDIT EDIT

Here's an extended and modified version which demonstrates:

- how to add further dependent variables (I didn't do 10 as I got bored, but I did get up to `\Enid`);
- how to accommodate both decimals and integers.

To print a variable, `\variable`, in a node, use

```
\node [print me=\variable] ;
```

Normally, a `\node` needs `{}`. However, in this case, the contents are being created by `print me`, which uses `node contents`.

If the node is created on an edge, you may need

```
... edge node [print me=\variable] {} ...
```

At least, I found I needed that.

`print me` expects a number. If you use e.g. `A`, you'll get an error. `\variable` is fine, as long as it produces a number. The code is configured to print the number up to 2 decimal places. Change the value of `precision` to alter this. If the number has fewer than 2 decimal places, no zeros will be printed. If the number is an integer, no decimal point will be printed.

Here's the code for the original case an an extended one.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\tikzset{%
  % key Anton stores a value in \Anton
  Anton/.store in=\Anton,
  % key double trouble sets \Berta to twice the argument it is given
  double trouble/.code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Berta{2*#1}%
    % additional dependent variables for demonstration purposes
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Carlos{4*(sqrt(#1))}%
    % we can use those we've just defined to create more
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Dave{atan(\Carlos/\Berta)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Enid{sqrt((\Carlos)^2 + (\Berta)^2)}%
  },
  % any time the key Anton is used, the same value will be passed to double trouble
  Anton/.forward to=/tikz/double trouble,
  % make sure the key Anton is set to something so \Anton and \Berta have some default value
  Anton=15,
  % this pretty-prints the argument, which should be a number (or something which produces a number)
  print me/.style={node contents={\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}},
  % this configures the printing of the numbers
  /pgf/number format/.cd,
  % we don't want decimal points in the case of integers; we don't want trailing zeros
  fixed,
  % print at most 2 decimal places - modify value as desired
  precision=2,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    x=1mm,
    y=1mm,
    mystyle/.style={<->},
    every node/.style={fill=white},
  ]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node (B) at (\Anton,0){B};
  \node (C) at (-\Berta,0){C};
  % Maße Verti
  % we can make this a bit more concise ...
  % notice the nodes are empty: print me=\variable puts the content in
  \path [mystyle] (A) edge node [print me=\Anton] {} (B) edge node [print me=\Berta] {} (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    x=1mm,
    y=1mm,
    mystyle/.style={<->},
    every node/.style={fill=white},
    Anton=15.5,
  ]
  \node (A) {A};
  \node (B) at (\Anton,0) {B};
  \node (C) at (-\Berta,0) {C};
  % use our new dependent variables
  \node (D) at (0,-\Carlos) {D};
  \path (C) ++(\Dave:\Enid) node (E) {E};
  % Maße Verti
  % we can make this a bit more concise ...
  \draw [mystyle] (A) edge node [print me=\Anton] {} (B) edge node [print me=\Berta] {} (C) edge node [print me=\Carlos] {} (D) [bend left] to (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: extended and original case]

Comment: I don't really see the advantage of using `\pgfkeys` over directly making a macro do the same thing. I think the logic is easier to understand with a macro (and the code runs much faster, it doesn't usually matter much but `\pgfkeys` is not exactly efficient). Compare: `\def\setAntonBerta#1{\def\Anton{#1}\pgfmathsetmacro\Berta{int(2*#1)}}`

Comment: I don't think efficiency is such a consideration here as the difference will be negligible. Ti*k*Z is loaded anyway and the macros are wanted for use in a `tikzpicture`. This method makes it easy to customise the values. And I certainly would not recommend the use of `\def` in a LaTeX document unless it is unavoidable. `\newcommand` is certainly preferable. Not in terms of speed, but in terms of safety. The advantage of using keys is the user-interface. It is also a more contained approach, although that isn't really an issue here as far as we know.

Comment: If you say `Anton/.show code`, you'll see that `Anton=#1` leads to `\def\Anton{#1}\pgfkeys {/tikz/double trouble={#1}}`, so the keys method is using a `\def` inside. You want to overwrite the value of `\Anton` anyways, so I don't see the issue.

Comment: @HoodChatham See edit. I think this is regrettable, myself, and that it would be better for PGF to be more careful. However, there isn't much choice, I suppose, if it is to be format-independent.

Comment: @HoodChatham But really, I think the reason to avoid `\def` has to do with habit. In that sense `\tikzset` does not have the same consequences. Although it could be argued that makes it all the more pernicious, of course. Anyway, my main reasons for doing it this way have to do with the user interface and flexibility.

Comment: For my real case I do have about 10 dependent variables. Having taken a closer look at how this is set up I would not have a clue how to expand this solution to accomodate my needs (within my resources). So this might be the over all better solution to do it right (I don't know if this is true) but for my case the solution by @HoodChatham seems to be more appropriate (despite the "inability" to use decimal numbers properly - but thats ok for me).

Comment: @MatoBehr You can add however many variables you want into the `double trouble` code ;). But without knowing more, it is hard to say much further. If you need sometimes decimals and sometimes integers, look at the pgfmath stuff for printing numbers and for detecting integers etc.

Comment: @MatoBehr Please see above for a way to deal with integers and decimals and/or to extend this to further dependent variables (I show 5, but obviously you can keep going).